# When using a HttpHandler to handle 404s in .NET 4.0, how to determine the current path?

Tags: c#, .net, http-status-code-404, httphandler

My app uses a `HttpErrors` rule in the `web.config` to redirect 404s to a custom `HttpHandler`:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="MyHandler" path="/default.aspx" verb="*" type="MyHandler.HttpHandler" />
</handlers>

<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <remove statusCode="405" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/default.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="405" path="/default.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

In .NET 2.0, this works fine. Now I want to convert my app to .NET 4.0, and it's causing problems.

The problem is that when a request is routed to the HttpHandler, I check the value of `Request.Path` to determine which page I'm looking at.

In .NET 2.0, the `Request.Path` would evaluate to i.e. `/page/subpage/item`. In .NET 4.0, it refers to `/default.aspx`.

Inspecting the `Request` gives me no other properties that look like something I could use - things like `RawUrl` and `Url` all include querystrings and other junk that I don't need. I just want the current path.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is your 2.0 vs 4.0 comparison done in the same version of IIS?

Comment: I think there's something else going on here, according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.path.aspx, you are using the correct property.

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes, I just toggle the Application Pool's .NET version and it changes the value of Request.Path immediately when debugging.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I thought so too, but I'm not a .NET expert (which may be obvious given that I'm a sucker running 2.0) and I'm wondering if anyone's seen something similar or may be able to point me in the right direction

Comment: @Rahul I'm thinking you have something wrong with the config (web.config) I would start there, but off the to of my head I don't see anything specific.

Comment: @Rahul - [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705934/how-do-i-find-out-which-request-path-is-missing-in-a-404-error-handler-in-iis7) a related question that might be able to help. I know you tried his answer but I was thinking maybe something in his configuration provided might be different.